# Input field not adjusting to desired width

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to make the search bar in the top right container responsive so that it shrinks down enough to so that its not being overlapped by the other icons, like this:

[What is happening when I have the window set to 600px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKm8C.png)

I am using media queries and css variables to make the site responsive.

So far I have tried to:

- Set a max-width with a hard pixel value for the
  input field with type text using css variables.
- Change the widths of all of the items in that row by
  hard coding it then using css variables.
- Added a margin-right to the text input field (which worked, but seemed wrong as in the "background" the icons are still overlapping the text field).

Would greatly appreciate any solutions to this problem.

[What I want the search bar row to look like for all window sizes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUw5Y.png)

PS. I know that the icons aren't loading, but I couldn't find a way to add them, but when I ran the code snippet on stackoverflow the output was still the same as what I'm seeing, just without the icons.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*---------------MEDIA QUERIES-----------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 20px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 15px;
        --container_padding: 15px;
        --header_height: 16.5vh;
        --content_height: 83.5vh;
        --search_max_width: 100px;
        --bg: orange;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) and (min-width: 360px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 25px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 17.5px;
        --container_padding: 12.5px;
        --header_height: 17.5vh;
        --content_height: 82.5vh;
        --search_max_width: 170px;
        --bg: orange;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) and (min-width: 375px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 30px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 20px;
        --container_padding: 15px;
        --header_height: 17.5vh;
        --content_height: 82.5vh;
        --search-max-width: 770px;
        --bg: orange;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width: 720px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 35px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 22.5px;
        --container_padding: 17.5px;
        --header_height: 17.5vh;
        --content_height: 82.5vh;
        --bg: orange;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1366px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 40px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 25px;
        --container_padding: 20px;
        --header_height: 17.5vh;
        --content_height: 82.5vh;
        --bg: black;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2300px) and (min-width: 1920px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 45px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 27.5px;
        --container_padding: 22.5px;
        --header_height: 11.5vh;
        --content_height: 88.5vh;
        --bg: black;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2300px) {
    :root {
        --sidebar_heading: 50px;
        --sidebar_sub_heading: 30px;
        --container_padding: 25px;
        --header_height: 12.5vh;
        --content_height: 87.5vh;
        --bg: black;
    }
    .home:hover, .profile:hover, .messages:hover, .history:hover, .tasks:hover, .settings:hover, .support:hover {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}

/*---------------MAIN CONTAINERS-----------------*/
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: var(--header_height) var(--content_height)/ min-content auto;
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

.sidebar-container {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    background-color: #1e3a8a;
    color: white;
}

.header-container {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-color: #cffafe;

}

.content-container {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(./images/wave.svg);
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.sidebar-container, .header-container, .content-container {
    padding: var(--container_padding);
}

/*---------------SIDEBAR STYLING-----------------*/
.row, .header-row-space-between, .header-row-end {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0 10px;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.header-row-space-between {
    width: 80%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-row-end {
    width: 20%;
    justify-content: end;
    gap: 0 40px;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.heading {
    font-size: var(--sidebar_heading);
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

.sub-heading {
    padding: 7.5px 0;
}

.settings {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.sub-heading, .settings {
    font-size: var(--sidebar_sub_heading);
    font-weight: 100;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-margin {
    margin-left: 10px;;
}

.image {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}


.box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
}
input[type='text'] {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    max-width: var(--search_max_width);
    width: 100%;
}
/*-----COLORS---------
    sidebar: #1e3a8a
    header: #cffafe
    content: #ecfeff
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sidebar-container">
        <div class="row heading">
          <img class="image" src="./images/icon.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Dashboard</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading home">
          <img class="image" src="./images/home.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Home</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading profile">
          <img class="image" src="./images/profile.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Profile</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading messages">
          <img class="image" src="./images/message.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Messages</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading history">
          <img class="image" src="./images/history.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">History</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading tasks">
          <img class="image" src="./images/task.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Tasks</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row settings">
          <img class="image" src="./images/settings.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Settings</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sub-heading support">
          <img class="image" src="./images/support.svg" />
          <div class="sidebar-margin">Support</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="header-row-space-between">
            <img class="icon" src="./images/search.svg" />
            <form action="">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="header-row-end">
            <img class="icon" src="./images/notification.svg" />
            <img class="icon" src="./images/person-profile.svg" />
            Hasin Mahmood
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think this would much easier to achieve without @media queries, using `display: grid` instead. Designing around so many width breakpoints can get really hairy, esp. when there is a more elegant solution.

For example:

```css
*{
  font-size: 3vmin;
}
header{
  display: grid;
  grid-template:  1fr / 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
h3{
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button>search</button>
  <input type="search"/>
  <button>icon</button>
  <button>icon 2</button>
  <h3>name here</h3>
</header>
```

By setting the sizes of the `grid` to fractional units, you will never have* elements overlapping one another, and will instead get `overflow-x` if the viewport becomes too small to display them all simultaneously.

To remedy the overflow issue, you then make the size of the elements *inside of the grid* relative to the viewport. For my example, I achieved this by setting the `font-size` to `3vmin`. However, you can instead use this for the size of the icons, the input box, whatever you want. If you desire, you can also set a minimum height to the `grid` itself, so that it retains its proportion relative to the rest of your document.

The other benefit of using `grid` in this case is that you will get reliable behavior out of justify-self and align-self, where you might not from the children of a `flexbox`.

Comment: Nice job distilling the HTML down, makes things very clear